# Filter the unique object by name from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to filter unique object from the places Array inside the list Array, but not able to get the exact solution to find the unique place name, please find the array data below=>

```
"list":[
   {
      "id":1,
      "uID": 1 
      "places":[
         {
            "name":"USA"
         },
         {
            "name":"USA"
         },
         {
            "name":"GER"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "uID":2
      "places":[
         {
            "name":"USA"
         },
         {
            "name":"GER"
         },
         {
            "name":"GER"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The Expected output should be like this =>

```
"list":[
   {
      "id":1,
      "uID": 1 
      "places":[
         {
            "name":"USA"
         },
         {
            "name":"GER"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "uID":2
      "places":[
         {
            "name":"USA"
         },
         {
            "name":"GER"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) to map to map each member of the list to a new value.

For each value, we can remove duplicate places using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object.

We instantiate the Set using an array of the place names, using .map() again. The Set will then contain a list of the unique place names.

We then assign this to the places property of each output item.

```js
const list = [ { "id":1, "uID": 1, "places":[ { "name":"USA" }, { "name":"USA" }, { "name":"GER" } ] }, { "id":2, "uID":2, "places":[ { "name":"USA" }, { "name":"GER" }, { "name":"GER" } ] } ]

const result = list.map(({ places, ...obj }) => {
    const uniquePlaces = new Set(places.map(item => item.name));
    return { ...obj, places: [ ...uniquePlaces].map(name => ({ name })) }
})

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set()` to filter duplicate by using `add()` method.
for more reference take a look at this link : https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-find-unique-values-by-property-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript-50ca23db8ccc

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the object(s) in `places` array as (JSON) string via `JSON.stringify()`.
2. With `new Set()` to distinct the JSON string.
3. Convert to array from result *2* via `Array.from()`.
4. Convert each (JSON) string in the array (from *3*) to the object via `JSON.parse()`.

```js
list = list.map(x => {
    x.places = Array.from([...new Set(x.places.map(x => JSON.stringify(x)))])
        .map(x => JSON.parse(x));

    return x;
})
```

[Sample Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBMCWDOkF4IG0CwAoCWDeGv4gCJoATQgLgEYAaPAogVwEkARCiSiWzewgB2ABDAMYhYFND3o460goQB2ggLYgKhAKoBlAIKFZ0gL7c5MqaaJLV67XoP1j9grnOnFKteUIBxAKIAlfVcCQycAXVlHKRdpYjJyACYTXmY2ROT5ARExCSd8GIssd2svWyCLKIsCwuLPHwDy00rTaota9T9AvKxQ4IipXrCAbgwMGHgIJHGwADplQT4ACgAPSYA+CFblmazRWEmIHQAnI8EATxmAMyOAe2VF5BmnhRAAdwgtcBWdoT25hZW6wgACktAB5AByM3gR2gCgA5tBLmcVgBKdFhVHdf5LVYIDagyE7QRHWAgNGokboAxHcAMI4KCDLKmGLHU9DCG4KWA3UAzYA3eGLaaooA)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const foo = {
"list":[
   {
      "id":1,
      "uID": 1,
      "places":[
         {
            "name":"USA"
         },
         {
            "name":"USA"
         },
         {
            "name":"GER"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "uID":2,
      "places":[
         {
            "name":"USA"
         },
         {
            "name":"GER"
         },
         {
            "name":"GER"
         }
      ]
   }
]};

const newList = foo.list.map(element => {
  let filteredPlaces = [];
  element.places.forEach(place => {
    const checkExistingPlaces = filteredPlaces.some(elem => elem.name === place.name);
    if (!checkExistingPlaces) {
      filteredPlaces.push(place);
    }
  });
  element.places = filteredPlaces;
  return element;
});

console.log(newList)
```